# Trouble accessing .Net web service using ksoap

Tags: android, .net, ksoap

I'm trying to call the DDI [Content Vault](http://ioun.wizards.com/ContentVault.svc?wsdl) service, used for Wizard's of the Coast's official D&D4E Character Builder, from an Android app using ksoap2-android, but unfortunately I keep getting HTTP status 415 whenever I call the Login method.  Since I'm trying to access someone else's service, I have no control over the server end, and can only work with the client side.

Here's a working request, sent from a Windows app:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IContentVaultService/Login</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:f12a29a6-0421-457a-b4e0-8d0c189907d1</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://ioun.wizards.com/ContentVault.svc</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <userName>Redacted, string</userName>
            <password>Redacted, byte array</password>
        </Login>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here's the response, indicating a successful login:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IContentVaultService/LoginResponse</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:f12a29a6-0421-457a-b4e0-8d0c189907d1</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
        </LoginResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IContentVaultService/Login";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://ioun.wizards.com/ContentVault.svc";
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapObject login = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Login");
PropertyInfo name = new PropertyInfo();
name.setName("userName");
name.setValue(uName);
name.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo pWord = new PropertyInfo();
pWord.setName("password");
pWord.setValue(simpleEncrypt(pass, uName));
pWord.setType(new byte[0].getClass());

request.addProperty(name);
request.addProperty(pWord);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

List<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Action", SOAP_ACTION));
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("To", URL));
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("ReplyTo", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous"));

HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerProperty);
```

In case anyone needs it, here's how the password is being encoded; it's giving the exact same results as my known good versions on other platforms, so I know it's working right.  Yes, I know that this isn't a good way of doing things, but I'm not the one that designed the darn thing.

```
private byte[] simpleEncrypt(String value, String key)
{
    MessageDigest digest = null;
    byte[] hash = null;
    byte[] IV = null;
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();
        hash = digest.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        IV = Arrays.copyOfRange(hash, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(hash, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);
        return cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        statusBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        status.setText(e1.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I could get the Login function to work, I could figure the rest out easily enough; any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Silly me, answering my own questions...

Turns out I was adding the headers wrong; what I was doing was adding them to the HTTP headers, when I needed to add it the the SOAP XML document.

Replace:

```
List<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Action", SOAP_ACTION));
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("To", URL));
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("ReplyTo", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous"));
```

With:

```
envelope.headerOut = buildHeader();
```

And add this function to build the headers:

```
        private Element[] buildHeader() {
            List<Element> headers = new ArrayList<Element>();
            Element action = new Element().createElement("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Action");
            action.addChild(Node.TEXT, SOAP_ACTION);
            action.setAttribute("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "mustUnderstand", "1");
            headers.add(action);

            Element to = new Element().createElement("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "To");
            to.addChild(Node.TEXT, URL);
            to.setAttribute("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "mustUnderstand", "1");
            headers.add(to);

            Element replyto = new Element().createElement("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "ReplyTo");
            Element address = new Element().createElement("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Address");
            replyto.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, address);
            address.addChild(Node.TEXT, "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");
            replyto.setAttribute("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "mustUnderstand", "1");
            headers.add(replyto);

            int size = headers.size();
            Element[] array = new Element[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
                array[i] = headers.get(i);
            return array;
        }
```

As a side note, it would appear the MessageID field isn't actually needed, as I'm receiving successful login responses without it.